# Use of declaration and/or definition array of tuple

Tags: nim-lang

How to have and declare/define array of tuple[ string , seq[ array[2,string] ] ]

Illustration is

```
  var
    a : seq[tuple[ string , seq[array[ 2, string]] ] ]
    
  a[0] = [ "foo", [ ["hello", "foo"], ["foo", "bar" ] ] ]
  a[1] = [ "bar", [ ["hello", "world"], ["hello", bar"] ] ]
  a[2] = [ "hello", [ ["foo","bar"], ["hello","world"], ["bar", "baz"] ] ]
    .
    .
    .
  a[n] =
```

Tried rather long in this variations, e.g.

```
a = newSeqOfCap[ (string, newSeqOfCap[ array[ 2, string]](40) ) ](9)
```

all just end with no avail
Please guide the correct way. Thanks in advance for sincere help

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `newSeq`, not `newSeqOfCap`. The latter only allocates the space for the sequence, not actually put anything in there for you to modify.

```
var a = newSeq[(string, seq[array[2, string]])](n)

a[0] = ("foo", @[["hello", "foo"], ["foo", "bar"]])
a[1] = ("bar", @[["hello", "world"], ["hello", "bar"]])
a[2] = ("hello", @[["foo", "bar"], ["hello", "world"], ["bar", "baz"]])
.
.
.
a[n] = ...
```